# Concurrent erode or dilate on bitmap

Tags: c++, algorithm, image-processing, concurrency, openmp

I need to do a morphological operation (a specialized version of dilate/erode) on a bitmap.
In order to accelerate, I am using openmp to parallelize the process:

```
  int* bitmap = ...;              // pointer to bitmap data with width and height
#pragma omp parallel for
   for(long iy=0; iy<height; iy++) 
      for(long ix=0; ix<width; ix++) 
         if(write_pattern(ix,iy)) 
            apply_pattern(ix,iy, 0);   // writes "0" to bitmap, write only, no read
```

That means at certain locations a pattern of constant values is written to the output bitmap. Since the 'pattern' may span several lines it is clear that several threads write the same value to the same memory location concurrently. It appears to work, but it looks a bit shady.

Is this ok, or what would be the recommended way of doing this?

Comment: What you describe sounds not ok - but it's impossible to give a specific answer without a [mcve].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't mind the parallelization too much, but I would like to point out that parallelizing dilation/erosion is not the first choice I would choose here.

With dilation/erosion you perform max/min operations on a structuring element around your pixel. If you have, for instance, a 5x5 window you look at, you look at 25 pixels for each pixel, so in essence you look at each pixel 25 times. So, your computational complexity for each pixel is proportional to the size of the structuring element in pixels with this naive approach.

With more efficient algorithms for computing morphological operators, you can bring this complexity down, even to constant complexity (per pixel) regardless of the size of the structuring element. There's a lot of literature on this, I'm including a few references in the end, they cite other papers as well and make comparisons.

I don't know the context you are working in, and how important performance is. But parallelization would be the last step I'm doing. First, I would make the algorithm run regardless of performance. Once I'm happy with that (or so annoyed by the run-time I'm willing to do something about it), I improve to a more efficient solver. If in the end, I still need to push run-time a bit, I parallelize (or think whether it makes sense going to a GPU).

If you parallelize now, you maybe get some speedup, but you lose out on algorithmic improvements that improve performance.

And now, as promised, two papers about efficient morphological filters:
[Petr Dokládal, Eva Dokladalova. Computationally efficient, one-pass algorithm for morphological
filters. Journal of Visual Communication and Image Representation, Elsevier, 2011](https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-00692897/document), this one presents an O(1) algorithm in terms of the structuring element and compares/cites classic efficient algorithms.
[Joseph Gil, Ron Kimmel. Efficient Dilation, Erosion, Opening and Closing
Algorithms](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.4.1969&rep=rep1&type=pdf) Also seems nice. I haven't read it in detail, but I know Ron Kimmel from my field of research and it's likely a good one.

Comment: Good answer. Algorithmics beat parallelism for performance most days, though they can take more effort to code.

Comment: Although not 100% applicable to my problem, it brought me to the conclusion to split the structuing element into pieces, whose pixels lie at consecutive memory locations. Now I process these segments in parallel. This gives the following advantages: the segments are not overlapping (no racy writes) and better cache utilization.

Answer (score 2):

OpenMP is a shared-memory paradigm. If you can guarantee that all of your different processes are going to write the same values to the same locations, then it is fine to have them do so. There are race conditions, but they will not affect the result.

That gives you this for code:

```
int* bitmap = ...;              // pointer to bitmap data with width and height

#pragma omp parallel for collapse(2)
for(long iy=0; iy<height; iy++) 
for(long ix=0; ix<width; ix++) 
  if(write_pattern(ix,iy)) 
    apply_pattern(ix,iy, 0);   // writes "0" to bitmap, write only, no read
```

If you can't make such a guarantee, you could use a critical section to restrict write access:

```
int* bitmap = ...;              // pointer to bitmap data with width and height

#pragma omp parallel for collapse(2)
for(long iy=0; iy<height; iy++) 
for(long ix=0; ix<width; ix++) 
  if(write_pattern(ix,iy)) {
    #pragma omp critical
    apply_pattern(ix,iy, 0);   // writes "0" to bitmap, write only, no read      
  }
```

But, if you can't make such a guarantee, this is a **bad** candidate for parallelism, since different processes will reach different parts of the bitmap at different times each time you run your code. That is, the order of execution is non-deterministic, so you will be unable to predict the outcome. Assuming there's only one right outcome, your processes *must* produce the same outputs.

Similarly, be sure you are using `apply_pattern()` to alter something other than your original data, or your result will, again, be non-deterministic since one thread may modify the input before or after another thread sees the modified section.

Another strategy would be to collect all of the places that need modifying and then write them serially later. This might make sense if your check is expensive but your writing is cheap; say, if you're using a regex for the check and writing out zeros.

```
int* bitmap = ...;              // pointer to bitmap data with width and height

typedef std::pair<long,long> gridloc;
std::vector<gridloc> patterns;

//Use a custom reduction operator, available in newer versions of OpenMP
#pragma omp declare reduction (merge : std::vector<gridloc> : omp_out.insert(omp_out.end(), omp_in.begin(), omp_in.end()))
#pragma omp parallel for collapse(2) reduction(merge:patterns)
for(long iy=0; iy<height; iy++) 
for(long ix=0; ix<width; ix++) 
  if(write_pattern(ix,iy)) {
    patterns.emplace_back(ix,iy)
  }

for(const auto &c: patterns)
  apply_pattern(c.first,c.second, 0);   // writes "0" to bitmap, write only, no read
```

If writing is expensive, you could do some processing on the contents of `patterns` to combine writes, eliminate redundant writes, topologically sort writes, &c.

Comment: I'd like to summarize this answer briefly: If you use parallelism, don't change your input image, but write to a different (output) image.

Comment: And adding to it: Don't write to your input image for filters like these if you don't use concurrency, either, unless you know exactly what you are doing and the effect is part of your algorithm.

Comment: I finally found an [argument](https://software.intel.com/en-us/blogs/2013/01/06/benign-data-races-what-could-possibly-go-wrong) why it may not work, even if the threads "produce the same output". What the compilers do is sometimes a bit scary.